# Чому вислови "крилаті"?

Tags: етимологія

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

> ***Крила́ті слова́ (крила́ті ви́слови, крила́ті фра́зи)*** — сталі словесні
>   формули (влучні вислови, звороти мови, окремі слова).
>
> До крилатих слів належать:
>
> -висловлювання відомих осіб (письменників, політиків, громадських діячів та ін.);
>
> -назви історичних та міфологічних подій, що набули переносного значення;
>
> -власні імена історичних, міфологічних та літературних персонажів, які мають символічне значення тощо.

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/krylatyj)

> ▲ Крилаті слова; ***Крилатий вислів (вираз)***; Крилата фраза — влучна
>   словосполука, влучний вислів літературного походження, що стисло й
>   образно передають думку й стали загальновживаними.

Чому саме ***"крилаті вислови"***? Яка етимологія цього словосполучення?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Словосполучення отримало своє термінологічне значення після виходу [книги Ґеорґа Бюхмана «Geflügelte Worte»](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gefl%C3%BCgelte_Worte), що дослівно означає «окрилені слова».

[image: Книга Geflügeltes Worte]

Український варіант є, вочевидь, калькою з німецької.

Comment: дослівно, думаю, таки означає "окрилені слова".

Comment: @P.Vovk, точно, дякую!

Comment: У [«Великій російській енциклопедії»](https://bigenc.ru/linguistics/text/2638018) шлях розписано трохи докладніше: «Вислів „крилаті слова“ (метафорич. образ – „слова, що вилітають з вуст мовця“) взято з поем Гомера. В кін. 18 ст. його вжив нім. поет Ф. Г. Клопшток. В ролі філологіч. термина введено Г. Бюхманом (Німеччина) в кн. „Geflügelte Worte“ (1864)».